# Как найти все li элементы которые содержат ul

Tags: javascript

Как найти и выделить только li элементы (elem 1.3, 2.3), которые содержат ul? Этот список может быть динамический, поэтому мы не знаем сколько вложенностей может быть. Используя только javascript, без jquery.

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>elem 1.1</li>
  <li>elem 1,2</li>
  <li>elem 1.3
    <ul>
      <li>elem 2.1</li>
      <li>elem 2.2</li>
      <li>elem 2.3
        <ul>
          <li>elem 3.1</li>
          <li>elem 3.2</li>
          <li>elem 3.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>elem 1.4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: и где ваш код без jquery с только javascript?

Comment: Если внутри `li` больше нет тегов по определению, то достаточно будет в твоем `ul` с классом `list` выполнить `document.querySelectorAll('li')`, а в каждом найденном проверить на совпадение через `.childNodes[i].tagName == 'UL'`. Можно отсеять таким образом и вывести. Весь код лень писать прост.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS версия:

```js
var obj_list = document.querySelector('#list'),
    objs_list_li = obj_list.querySelectorAll('li');

// Перебираем все li в #list
for(var i = 0; i < objs_list_li.length; i++){
  // Получаем список ul находящиеся в li
  var objs_li_ul = objs_list_li[i].querySelectorAll('ul');
  
  // Если li имеет ul, то применяем к заголовку стиль
  if( objs_li_ul.length ){
    objs_list_li[i].querySelector('.title').style.color = 'red';
  };
};
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.1</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1,2</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.1</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.2</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.3</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.1</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.2</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.4</span></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery версия:

```js
var $list_li = $('#list li');

$list_li.filter(function() {return $(this).children('ul').length !== 0}).children('.title').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.1</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1,2</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.1</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.2</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.3</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.1</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.2</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.4</span></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATA:**

Ещё один JS вариант

```js
var e_list = document.querySelector('#list'),
    E_listItem = e_list.querySelectorAll('li');
    
// Перебираем все пункты
E_listItem.forEach(function (e) {
  // Проверяем наличие списка в пункте и если список есть, то красим заголовок
  if (e.querySelectorAll('ul').length) e.querySelector('.title').style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.1</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1,2</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.1</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.2</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.3</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.1</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.2</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Слишком замудренно получилось, но как мне кажется, исключительно производительно (:

Проверить работу можешь, открыв консоль в браузере.

```js
'use strict';

var list = document.querySelector('#list'),
    listLi = Array.apply(null, list.querySelectorAll('li')),

    listLiWithUl = listLi.filter(function(listLiItem) {
      var listLiItemChildNodes = Array.apply(null, listLiItem.childNodes);
      return listLiItemChildNodes.find(function(listLiItemChild) {
       return listLiItemChild.tagName == 'UL' ? true : false;
      });
    });

console.log(listLiWithUl);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.1</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1,2</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.1</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.2</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">elem 2.3</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.1</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.2</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">elem 3.3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="title">elem 1.4</span></li>
</ul>
```